# Flask redirect alternative in Seldon core

Tags: python, flask, seldon-core

I have a kibana dashboard where there are some links provided for the user to click on. The link calls a flask service, which does some processing and redirects an URL using `flask's redirect API`, so that Kibana dashboard shows the processed values.  Now, the flask is replaced with seldon core for predictions. Is there any way to redirect an URL, like it can be done in flask?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah I had a read this is not something you can do easily maybe not at all. Seldon core provides you with a ready build service which takes in your prediction model and return the results. I dont think you can and more importantly i dont think you should use that as a web app. It is meant to be used with the micro-service logic that I explained below in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you completely removed the flask app? If not you can use the flask to handle all interactions with the frond end and just use Seldon for the predictions.

This is a micro-services approach. You can receive the request as you used to in flask and then from within flask call the Seldon micro-service, get the prediction and then redirect to the results page with the new results from within flask.

This is good because if you change your prediction logic or tools in the future you wont have to redo all this work. You ll just change the function that flask calls to get the results. Also you frond end and back-end will be agnostic of the implementation details of the prediction method.

Comment: Unfortunately, flask has been removed completely.

Comment: So what you need exactly then? A way to pass data to Kibana? How was that don ein flask did you send an http request with the data to Kibana? Do you have the code that did this before, if you add it in the question maybe I can help

Comment: Yes, need a way to pass the data back to Kibana. Earlier, within the function, I was returning the URL using this code: `return redirect(kibana_url+"?_a=(<required_query>)", 301)`. `kibana_url` variable would be filled with the URL detail from Config.

Comment: ok but wait a sec what service does the button on Kibana calls now? it calls the seldon directly?

Comment: From what I am reading seldon is not meant to work as a web application, I dont think you can redirect to a page. It is meant to run prediction models not run web applications

Comment: Yes, the button calls the seldon service directly. Yeah, this is where I'm facing the issue. It is running the prediction models and I can return the prediction as a JSON response. This response somehow has to be redirected to Kibana. Is there a better way to do this? (I'm being dumb here, may be through some JavaScript/requests object)

Comment: The only way I see is to build a super super light and simple one page web app (literally a single page) and make it act as the intermediate service between Kibana and Seldon. Seldon is DEFINITELY not meant to do what you are trying to do. I dont think it is possible. It is build to work as a microservice. So you could still use a simple one page flask app and handle everything there as I suggested in my initial response. Anything else seems hacky, way to much work and definitelly not very well thought out.

Comment: Basically what you need is this flow: kibana-> web app->seldon->web app -> new request to kibana

Comment: seldon runs a pre-built service..is it possible to turn it into a web app? maybe I am not sure, I don't think so..should you do it if possible? NO

Comment: Ok, let me try something. Thanks for your support all the way

Comment: no problem I hope you build it, I am keep looking btw to see if you can hack the seldon service somehow, but I cant find anything.The only way to do it seems is to change the seldon code itlsef..but that is waaayy much more work. Goodluck anyway

Comment: oh btw if you do find a way please post it here. If you go through the path I described please consider voting up and mark as preferred. cheers